# Cannot deploy static website on azure via Git

Tags: git, azure, kudu

I have a simple project structure in my Git repository.

```
[repo]
  - api  (Contains a .NET WebApi application)
  - client
    - dist  (Contains a static html/js website using AngularJS)
```

I set up continuous deployment from Bitbucket for the `api` directory to an Azure Website without any glitches. I set up an App Setting named `project` and set the value to `api/ProjectName.csproj` and it works great.

I created a separate Azure website and tried to set up continuous deployment the same way for the static website, but it doesn't work.  I created an App Setting named `project` with the value `client/dist`.

When it attempts to deploy, I get the following error message in the error log.

> Unable to determine which solution file to build.
>   C:\DWASFiles\Sites\flighty\VirtualDirectory0\site\repository\MyProject.sln,
>   C:\DWASFiles\Sites\flighty\VirtualDirectory0\site\repository\client\components\moment-datepicker\MomentDatepicker.sln.

Answer (score 3):

This scenario is a little trickier now than it should be, but here is a way you should be able to get this working.

You'll need to generate a [custom deployment script](http://blog.amitapple.com/post/38418009331/azurewebsitecustomdeploymentpart2). Call it as follows:

```
azure site deploymentscript --basic -p client\dist
```

This will generate both a .deployment file and a deploy.cmd file. Don't commit the .deployment file as it will mess up your WebAPI scenario. Instead, in your static site:

- Rename deploy.cmd to DeployStaticSite.cmd (this is optional, just to be clear what it does). Commit this file.
- In the Azure portal app settings, set `command` to `DeployStaticSite.cmd`. Get rid of your `project` setting.

Comment: Hey David, thanks for your answer.  I followed your instructions and ended up getting the exact same error message as before.  I even FTPed into the `repository` directory to make sure that the `DeployStaticSite.cmd` file was actually there, and it was.  I made sure I had the correct App Setting (name: `command`, value: `DeployStaticSite.cmd`).  Not sure why this isn't working for me.

Comment: So does it look like the COMMAND app setting is getting ignored completely? For me, it's effective. e.g. I just tried setting it to `bogus.cmd` (which doesn't exist), and it blew up with `'bogus.cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command`

Comment: It would appear that way. Is the app setting name case sensitive?

Comment: It's not case sensitive. I just tried `command` and it works fine. You may need to share a minimal repro for investigation (e.g. on github), in case something you have in there explains the difference.

Comment: This is an amazing way to generate deployment scripts. Thanks. Hopefully  Azure team will bring it into Azure dashboard, so all we need to do is, just select branch and files to deploy. This is pretty much what kudu deployment script is doing.